# matlab get_param for scope

Tags: matlab, scripting, simulink

I need to change the variable name of a scope.
How can I do it with code?

Seems `get_param` does not work for scopes.

```
get_param('untitled/scope','DialogParameters')

ans = 

struct with no fields.
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To discover (most/many of) the settable/gettable properties for the standard library blocks have a look at the first link returned by

```
>> docsearch('Block-Specific Parameters')
```

Specifically, for the variable you are looking for,

```
>> get_param('untitled/Scope','SaveName')
ans =
ScopeData
>> set_param('untitled/Scope','SaveName','NewName')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your method works. However, `dosearch` opens up a help page. On which part of the manual can I find `SaveName`?

Comment: Click the first link.  It takes you to a page listing all the libraries.  Click on the Sources library, it scrolls you down to a list of the properties of each of the blocks.  Look for the Scope block, and look at the listed properties.